# React: Child don't update parent's state

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, state

I'm new to React and I was trying to create a Modal using mui that opens and closes based on parent's state.
The problem is that the modal opens well based on state but upon closing, the modal onClose function works well, but when I click on Button that has the same with the same update state function it doesn't work.

Here's my parent component

```
 const TableIcon = props => {
    const {title,icon}=props;
        // handling modal functionality
        const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false);
        const handleModalOpen = () => {
          setModalOpen(true);
        };
        const handleModalClose = () => {
          setModalOpen(false);
        };
        console.log('modal', modalOpen)
  return (
    <button className={styles.button} title={title} onClick={()=>handleModalOpen()}>
    {icon}
    <ActionModal
          open={modalOpen}
          handleClose={handleModalClose}
          handleOpen={handleModalOpen}
        />
    
  </button>
  )
}
```

and here is the modal component

```
  const ActionModal=(props)=> {
const {open,handleOpen,handleClose}=props;
console.log(props,'modal')

  return (
    <div>
      <Modal
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
      >
        <Box  className={styles.box}>
            <div className={styles.header}>
                <div className={styles.icon}>
                    <BsFillTrashFill/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className={styles.content}>
                <h2>You are about to delete a school</h2>
                <h3>School Name/Tuituion</h3>
                <p>This will delete the school from the database
                    Are you sure?</p>
                
            </div>
            <div className={styles.footer}>
                <Button color='var(--unnamed-color-ffffff)' name='Cancel' onClick={handleClose}/>
                <Button color='var(--unnamed-color-f53748)' name='Confirm'/>
            </div>
           

        </Box>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and here is the button component

```
const Button=(props)=>{
const {color,onClick,icon,name}=props;
return <div className={styles.container} style={{background:color}} onClick={()=>onClick()}>
    {icon}
    <span>{name}</span>
</div>
```

}

and the Button onClick works just fine
[image]

Comment: Could you be more specific about what exactly isn't working? I'm having trouble understanding.

Comment: the handleClose function passed to Button.js doesn't change TableIcon.js state, hope I could clarify it well

Comment: try logging onClick within the button component, if possible please share a reproducible link

Comment: I have already checked, and it works fine. I edited the original post with a screenshot to the console log when I click the button

Comment: Not sure why it isn't working. The onyl thing that comes to my mind that could fix it  could be this line: onClick={()=>onClick()} to onClick={onClick}

Comment: I have already tried this, but still doesn't work.

Comment: i have been looking at this for last 20min and yet cant figure out whats going wrong! one thing u can change is from button onClick={()=>onClick()} to onPress={()=> onClick()}

Comment: I believe you mean to change the prop name passed to Button.js from onClick to onPress, I have tried this too, but doesn't work also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `<ActionModal>` component is *inside* the `<button>` tag. So when clicking the **Cancel** button in the modal you first get the call to `handleModalClose`, immediately followed by the call to `handleModalOpen`, because the "click" is getting passed to the button that opens the modal.

You need to change the code in `<TableIcon>` to something like:

```
return (
    <>
      <button title={title} onClick={() => handleModalOpen()}>
        {icon}
      </button>
      <ActionModal open={modalOpen} handleClose={handleModalClose} />
    </>
  );
```

You can use this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-w1ynqj?file=src/App.js) example.